# Only toggle certain elements based on class

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a simple table:

```
<table>
    <tr class="header">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level2">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level3">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level3">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level2">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level3">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level3">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This works great to toggle everything from one "header" to the next.

```
$('.header').click(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').toggle();
});
```

But what I can't figure out how to do is to ONLY toggle the elements with class of "level2" and leave "level3" hidden.

I've been playing around for a while with .toggleClass() and .netAll() but I am not getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use filter to select the items

```js
$('.header').click(function () {
    var trs = $(this).nextUntil('tr.header')
    trs.filter('.level2').toggle();
    trs.filter('.level3').hide();
});
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: green;
}

.level2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.level3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="header">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level2">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level3">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level3">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level2">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level3">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level3">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your first example worked too, before the edit. What's the advantage of the way you are doing it after the edit?

Comment: I re-read your question and it made it sound like you wanted level3 hidden. So I edited it and hid level3

Answer (score 1):

You can fill in the `filter` parameter of [`nextUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to select only the elements you want, in this case:

```
$(this).nextUntil('tr.header', '.level2').toggle();
//                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

**Example:**

```js
$('.header').click(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header', '.level2').toggle();
});
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: green;
}

.level2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.level3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="header">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level2">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level3">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level3">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level2">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level3">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="level3">
        <th>
            ....
        </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```